# How to expand a list of dict in presto db

Tags: sql, presto

I have a column in prestodb that is a list of dictionaries:

```
[{"id": 45238, "kind": "product", "name": "Ball", "category": "toy"}, {"id": 117852, "kind": "service", "name": "courier", "category": "transport"}]
```

is a there a way to expand this column to get something like this:

```
id     kind      name      category
4528   product   Ball      toy
117852 service   courier   transport
```

Also sometimes the key's can be different from the example above also can have more key's than the 4 above

I am trying:

```
with cte as ( select cast(divs as json) as json_field from table)
select m['id'] id, 
    m['kind'] kind,
    m['name'] name,
    m['category'] category
from cte
cross join unnest(cast(json_field as array(map(varchar, json)))) as t(m)
```

Error:

```
INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast to array(map(varchar, json)). Expected a json array, but got [{"id": 36112, "kind"....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data contains json - you can cast it to array of maps from varchar to json (`array(map(varchar, json))`) and then use `unnest` to flatten the array:

```sql
WITH dataset (json_str) AS (
    VALUES (json '[{"id": 45238, "kind": "product", "name": "Ball", "category": "toy"}, {"id": 117852, "kind": "service", "name": "courier", "category": "transport"}]')
) 

select m['id'] id, 
    m['kind'] kind,
    m['name'] name,
    m['category'] category
from dataset
cross join unnest(cast(json_str as array(map(varchar, json)))) as t(m)
```

| id | kind | name | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45238 | product | Ball | toy |
| 117852 | service | courier | transport |

**UPD**

If original column type is varchar - use [`json_parse`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse) to convert it to json.

Comment: it returns the error: `Cannot cast varchar to array(map(varchar, json))` Is there a way to convert it first to json?

Comment: @noob4ever yes -  `cast(you_column_name as json)`

Comment: still fails.  I updated my question with code I am using!

Comment: @noob4ever my bad. try `json_parse(divs)` instead of cast to json.